# ngBootstrap for Angular 4 DatePicker in a Reactive Form is Always Required

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

Using a reactive form I've added the ngbDatePicker:

```
<input type="text"
        id="business_incorp_date"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="business_incorp_date"
        ngbDatepicker
        #incorporatedDatePicker="ngbDatepicker"
        (click)="incorporatedDatePicker.toggle()"
        readonly>
```

For a form model of:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [
    0, [Validators.required]
  ],

  // ... removed for brevity

  business_type: [
    '', [Validators.required]
  ],
  business_incorp_date: [
    '', [FormValidators.date] // <-- NOT REQUIRED BY MODEL
  ],
  business_desc: [
    '', [Validators.required]
  ]

  // ...
});
```

But, if the field is empty it is still ngInvalid for the `ngbDateFormat`:

```
{ "ngbDate": { "invalid": { "year": null, "month": null, "day": null } } }
```

Anyone know how to make the DatePicker field allow for an empty string?

Comment: See: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1582#issuecomment-304204567

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer provided by @pkozlowski.opensource via [github issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1582#issuecomment-304204567) that states that the model must be set to null to avoid validation on optional fields.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've lost a lot of time trying to get a correct way to this. And EASY!